# How can I return a response Body with Spring Rest MVC when i have also to return a Web page for MVC process?

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller, jax-rs

This is my Code, i know that i should not make 2 return statements, but just for explaining my issue. Thanks

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.Created)
public String addStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
    return StudentRep.save(Student);// Should be PayLoad Client Response
    return “Student”; // Should be redirect to Student.html

}
```

Comment: What do you want to return? It's not very clear - what's the response body, what's the web page? Or do you mean that you should return different things based on the content type requested?

Comment: My need is to redirect to a thymeLeaf page , and that should be done by returning the name of the page as a String.
And I also want to return a Student saved by the POST request as a Payload.
Like an normal POST , when adding a ressource by POST method , we should return the new Ressource added. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a ResponseBody. You can simply add attributes to your Model and then use them in your views.

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.Created)
public String addStudent(@RequestBody Student student, Model model){
    String id = StudentRep.save(Student);// Should be PayLoad Client Response
    model.addAttribute("studentId", id);
    // Will redirect to Student.html where you can use the id attribute.
    return “Student”; 
}
```

Now, if you were using `Thymeleaf`, you could use this new attribute anywhere you want in your template. I am not sure how you are creating your templates, so I just used `Thymeleaf` as an example.

```
<p th:text=${id}></p>
```

Now if you want to return a Stundet object, you would need to the following changes to your controller.

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.Created)
public String addStudent(@RequestBody Student student, Model model){
    StudentRep.save(Student);// Should be PayLoad Client Response
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    // Will redirect to Student.html where you can use the student attribute.
    return “Student”; 
}
```

Comment: So if I rely your answer, it means that if I put the an url in (Postman) like .
POST localhost:8080/myApp/student and provide a Payload of the student a wanna post .(What's Postman response should be ? )
basically Postman returns the Payload of a the new Student added, but in my example a dont return a Student , but i return a String for Thymeleaf needs.

FI: the Thymeleaf part is okey

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I know that Hibernates `save()` actually returns a serializable identifier of the newly persisted entity. Although, I have never use it with String identifiers, but I guess it should work as well. I just edited my answer to reflect this changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i find the solution of my answer.
I should annotate the controller that contains my method by **@RestController** instead of **@Controller**.
So then, the response will automatically return a **JSON HTTP** response.